# Is it wrong to write an integral within an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've got a question asking me to define $u$ and $dv$ in $\int xe^{2x}dx$ so that I integrate it using "integration by parts" (and it says not to evaluate the integral).

I did this:

$$ \int udv = uv - \int vdu$$

let $ u = x \Rightarrow du = u'dx = dx $

let $ dv = v'dx = e^{2x}dx \Rightarrow v = \int e^{2x}dx$

$$ \int udv = uv - \int vdu$$

$$\int xe^{2x}dx = x\int e^{2x}dx - \int [\int e^{2x}dx]dx$$

but is this the correct way to write this ?( or hell is it even the right way to do this in the first place)

Comment: Don't think of it as right or wrong, think of it as a lifestyle choice.

Comment: damn this got alot bigger all of a sudden lol

Comment: $$v=\int e^{2x}dx = \frac 12 e^{2x}$$

Comment: @amWhy so do i just evaluate that part then use it ? that's easier that's for sure

Comment: Indeed; it does make it more straightforward.

Comment: @amWhy okay thanks i'll do that

Comment: You can double check with my answer below.

Comment: I kind of have to wonder what they mean "not to evaluate the integral," since there are at least four integrals involved in a typical integration by parts: $\int u\,dv,$ $\int v\,du,$ $\int dv,$ and of course the original integral you are trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidK no idea myself either, this book isn't exactly one for actually explaining what it wants tbh

Comment: TBH I get a little unhappy about how integration by parts is presented most of the time. It makes more sense to me that you choose $u$ and $v$ (not $u$ and $dv$) in order to make your original integral be $\int u\,dv.$ Then you only have to differentiate $v,$ not even think about the integral of $dv.$ But if you start with $u$ and $dv$ as is often done, your notation actually makes a lot of sense to me. As long as you consistently use the same "$+C$" constant for $\int dv$ in both places when you actually evaluate, you'll be OK.

Comment: yeah, in any case it's a pretty weird method to use ( or atleast it is for someone who just learned to use it like me)

Comment: Your notation is confusing in the line "$u = x \to du = u'dx = dx$" because the arrow looks like an operator. Use words instead: "$u = x$, so $du = dx$".

Comment: @Théophile oh okay, well That's just the way my teacher does it, so I've picked that up too. Also i'm not really familiar with the difference between the arrow types all that much

Comment: @user464154 Ah, I see. Arrows are commonly used to show that a variable is approaching a constant or increasing to infinity; for example, "As $x \to \infty$, ...", or "$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =$ ...". So you can see why it might look like you mean that $x$ is approaching $du$ (which is nonsense). If you want to keep on using arrows, I suggest a double arrow instead ($\Rightarrow$), since this is understood as "therefore".

Comment: oh okay. yeah no wonder it caused confusion then lol. thanks, i'll be sure to use the double arrow from now on then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About the main question:**

The expression $$\int f(x)\,dx$$

denotes an antiderivative of the function $f$, which is also a function of $x$. Hence, you may use it wherever an ordinary function is used.

Comment: so does that include things like derivatives and integrals and the like as well?

Comment: @user464154: mh, can you formulate in a more precise way ?

Comment: lets say for example $\int (\frac{d}{dx} (e^{3x}) ) dx$ or $ \int ( \int lnx dx)dx$ , can the integral be used with things like this too?

Comment: Your first example is not an integral inside something, it is a derivative inside something. But all of this is possible.

Comment: okay, thanks m8.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. Yes, putting $u = x$ makes very good sense.

So $du= dx$.

And $$dv = e^{2x} \rightarrow \quad v=\int e^{2x}dx = \frac 12 e^{2x}$$

$$uv -\int vdu = x\left(\frac 12 e^{2x}\right)  - \frac 12 \int e^{2x} dx $$

$$ \int xe^{2x}dx = \frac 12(xe^{2x}) - \frac 14 e^{2x}+ C$$

$$= \frac 12 e^{2x}\left( x- \frac 12\right) +c$$

Answer (score 1):

One way might be

> $$\int  xe^{ 2x }dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { xd\left( { e }^{ 2x } \right)  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( x{ e }^{ 2x }-\int { { e }^{ 2x }dx }  \right) =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \left( x{ e }^{ 2x }-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } { e }^{ 2x } \right) +C$$

I didn't even understand your notation,for example $u = x \to du = u'dx = dx$

so you can write it as $$\begin{cases} u=x \\ dv=e^{ 2x }dx \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} du=dx \\ v=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } { e }^{ 2x } \end{cases}\\ \int { udv=uv-\int { vdu }  } =\frac { x{ e }^{ 2x } }{ 2 } -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { { e }^{ 2x } } dx=\frac { x{ e }^{ 2x } }{ 2 } -\frac { 1 }{ 4 } { e }^{ 2x }+C$$

Comment: but like i stated, it doesn't ask me to evaluate it. evaluating it I know how to , I just don't know if the thing i wrote in the question is wrong

Comment: thanks, I'll do that instead.